# Can I enable/disable/hide plugins on a per-site basis in multisite?

Tags: plugins, multisite

I'd like to be able to enable/disable plugins on a per-site basis in multisite, similar to the way that themes are per-site configurable. Is this currently possible?

(For instance, I don't particularly want people seeing the Domain Mapping plugin but want them to be able to enable Gravity Forms.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### [Multisite Plugin Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multisite-plugin-manager/)

> The essential plugin for every multisite install! Manage plugin access permissions across your entire multisite network.

Comment: Precisely what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

Network activated plugins are hidden from the normal site plugins menu, though they are active regardless.

Plugins installed that are not network activated are visible to individual sites and can be activated on a per-site basis.

Comment: That's the inverse of what I'm looking for, though. I want the plugins inactive and hidden, not active and hidden...

Comment: If it's inactive, then what good is it to be hidden? Just remove the plugin in that case. Having plugins you're not using, and that nobody is allowed to use, seems a bit pointless to me. But then maybe I just don't know your use case. :)

Comment: I want them to be selectable for certain blogs but not even an option for others. Useful for e.g. advanced users exposing advanced capabilities (like Markdown, etc.) while "protecting" n00bs from excess confusion and/or breakage.

Answer (score 0):

I use Exclude Plugins - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exclude-plugins/ - It works.

Comment: This one is displaying the **`"hasn't been updated in over 2 years"`** notice.

Comment: Make that 4 years.

Comment: Make that 12 years. lol

Comment: "This plugin has been closed as of December 23, 2018 and is not available for download. **Reason: Guideline Violation.**"